# Notification in iOS when Contacts sort order is changed

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

When I add or remove or change a contact in the Contacts app, my app gets notified since I have registered `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` in my `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

However, when I change the contacts *Sort Order* in the Mail, Contacts, Calendar setting in iPhone, I don't get any notification. Could anyone help me out with the name of the notification I should observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I figured it a solution myself. I delcare a iVar called `lastSortOrdering`. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, I initialize it

```
lastSortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
```

In applicationWillEnterForeground method

```
if(lastSortOrdering!=ABPersonGetSortOrdering()) {
    lastSortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
    NSLogDebug(@"Sort ordering was touched by user");
    //Perform contact fetching with new sort order
}
```

However, it would be nice if there is a notification of some sort to achieve this.